Internal server error happens after waiting for server response reaches 1min in browser/postman
Our application works well in server without ssl. after installing the internal ssl in the server, the api loads the data and browser throws internal server error only when the waiting for server response reaches 1min.
After it reaches 1min response we are getting as 500 internal server error. i have checked the logs and there was no error and in fact the data was loaded and the response was sent.
In https environment the api gets internal server error after waiting for server response reaches one minute.


but with the same api and payload in http environment executes even after one minute

we thought like we need set the request timeout in jboss server and ssl. after setting request timeout in jboss server(standalone.xml) we are still facing this issue.
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true" request-timeout="120000" connection-timeout="120000"/>

also i have tried to set the no request timeout in wildfly undertow file as mentioned below. still the issue was not fixed.
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/279379
can someone suggest any solutions?
note: we are not using proxy and we are using round robin load balancer.

If you are using a load balancer it means that the JBoss server must not secure the connection on it's own, but you have to configure the load balancer with TLS and the certificate - it has to "terminate" the secured connection from the client and pass it on (probably unsecured) to one of your servers.

Where do I have to set the request timeout in the load balancer or SSL?

Actually there are two timeouts to consider: one in the load balancer when it tries to reach your JBoss server (that could be down) and one in the JBoss server when internal processing takes too long (what you have now for https-listener - but you will have some other listener if configured correctly)

Currently we have hold this issue and raised the ticket to the infra team. will post answers, if we are able to solve this. and thanks for your suggestions.

we have fixed the issue by setting the timeout in the load balancer, Thanks for your valuable comment.
